# Entity Framework - GroupBy, OrderBy, Sum

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

I am trying to rewrite this query in Entity Framework (method syntax) but I can't. I don't understand what needs to be done first.

My Postgres query:

```
select id, Sum(yellow_hour) "yellow_hour"
from my_table
group by id
where date_part('day', date::timestamptz - '2022-10-30 00:00:00.000 +0200'::timestamptz) > 0
order by yellow_hour desc 
limit 20
```

My attempt:

```
var sensors = dbContext.mytable
                       .Where(x => x.Date >= instantStartDate && x.Date <= instantEndDate)
                       .GroupBy(x => x.id)
                       .ToList();
```

Error:

> Unable to translate the given 'GroupBy' pattern. Call 'AsEnumerable' before 'GroupBy' to evaluate it client-side.

Comment: i can't do the orderby and Sum the hours after i did the groupby id

Comment: Can you show us your attempt so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not having access to a compiler right now there might be some typo's but you will get the idea with the current LINQ query.

```
var queryDate = DateTime.Parse("2022-10-30 00:00:00.000 +0200");
db.my_table.Where(t=>t.date > queryDate).GroupBy(t => t.id).
              Select(g => new 
                {
                    g.Key, 
                    SUM = g.Sum(s=>s.yellow_hour)
                }).OrderByDescending(g=>g.SUM).Take(20);
```